# Arithmetic operations on MySQL variables on MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql

I have a table (test_table) in which some field values (say fields A, B and C) are inserted from an external application and one field (field D) whose values I want to insert from an existing table (store_table), but somehow randomly, after the former(A, B and C) have been inserted. I want to use an After Insert trigger to insert values in field D each time the other fields' values are inserted. My problem is that I'm not sure of the correct syntax to use for declaring and setting values for the variables and the arithmetic operations. Below is what I have tried, and the subsequent error generated.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER afterinsert_test_table_ABC
AFTER INSERT
ON test_table
BEGIN 


    SET @Id:=new.Id;


    SET @Id := SELECT ((7*@Id + 19) % 11);
    if @Id==0 THEN
        INSERT INTO test_table(D)VALUE(SELECT X FROM store_table WHERE store.Id=LAST_INSERT_ID());
      ELSE
          INSERT INTO test_table(D)VALUE(SELECT X FROM store_table WHERE store_table.Id=@Id); 
        END IF;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN SET @Id:=new.Id; SET @I' at line 4

Comment: 1) Syntax from user manual must be used. Server will never understand the syntax which you have made up for it. 2) Insert into the table which altering fires the trigger is not allowed.

Comment: If you were to take a moment to make your question readable, we would be more likely to help you [See how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

even eliminating your mistakes

You can't insert on to the same table.(Which would cause itself an new insert trigger

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER afterinsert_test_table_ABC
AFTER INSERT
ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    SET @Id:=new.Id;
    SET @Id :=  ((7*@Id + 19) % 11);
    if @Id = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO second_test_table (D) SELECT X FROM store_table WHERE store.Id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO second_test_table (D)  SELECT X FROM store_table WHERE store_table.Id=@Id; 
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```